# Add properties to a datatable generated in JSON format in ashx file

Tags: json, datatables

This is a part of my html:

```
        ...
        <section id="mainSection">
          <div id="MyDataTable"></div>
        </section>
        ...
```

The following javascript code generates my datatable:

```
function getData() {
    $('#MyDataTable').html('<table id="MyDataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>');
    $.ajax({
        "url": "myurl\getData.ashx"
        "success": function (json) {
             $('#MyDataTable').dataTable(json);
        },
        "dataType": "json"
    });
}
```

The getData.ashx file generates columns and content of the datatable:

```
        ...
        String Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List<Object>);
        String Columns = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List<Object>);
        context.Response.Write("{\"data\":" + Data + ",\"columns\":" + Columns + "}")
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I ADD PROPERTIES to my datatable. The property I want to add is `"defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"`  Everywhere I look on the internet, datatables are generated differently, e.g. -

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null {
            "data": "first_name",
            //THIS IS THE PROPERTY I AM TRYING TO ADD 
            "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"
        }
    ]
});
```

I can't add a property the way it was done in this example because the generation of my table is different. How do I do it then? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just append the feature in the `success` handler?

```
"success": function(json) {
   json.columnDefs = [{
     targets: '_all',
     defaultContent: '<i>Not set</i>'
   }];
   $('#MyDataTable').dataTable(json);
}
```

You could do that with other features / properties as well.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Do you also happen to know how to add the default button (e.g. print) properties to the same example?

Comment: @JerryBox The same way: `json.dom = 'Bfrtip'; json.buttons = [ 'print' ];`  And remember to include the `dataTables.buttons.js` and `buttons.print.js` files.